# Selenium Webdriver script: Handling Browser sessions in Try and Finally Sessions

Tags: selenium-webdriver

What happens if we close the driver/browser(via `driver.quit()` or `driver.close()`) in try block, then will the Finally block execute or not.

Comment: Please provide more context to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally block will be executed at any cost. But, if you try to do any operation on driver in finally block (as driver session is ended in try block), you will get NoSuchSesionException, which will fail your test scenario

Comment: In normal Java programs - there is only scenario wherein finally block will not be executed. i.e. if we add sys.exit(not sure about the exact syntax) in Try block. So wrt to above selenium related question, finally will be skipped/not executed or it will go into finally block and try to execute the code and throw exception as you have mentioned. (I am aware that this is not a real time scenario)

Comment: You can check this code:                                                                             import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class Test {
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  
  driver.get("https://www.google.com");
  
  try {
   driver.quit();
  } finally {
   System.out.println("This is to test finally after driver gets closed");
  }
 }

}

Comment: Above code will execute successfully and prints the message even though driver is closed. In case System.exit(), entire JVM will gets shutdown and nothing to proceed. But in case of driver, we are not completed/shutdown JVM here.